# How can I prevent dragstart from firing after dragend on a rapidly dragged element?

Tags: javascript, events, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

In my application, I set the opacity of my dragged element to 0.4  in `dragstart` and restore it to 1 in `dragend`. This works fine for the most part except when a user drags an element very quickly in which case the first dragstart event is fired followed by the first dragend before a **final second `dragstart` event** which is **NOT** accompanied by a `dragend` so the opacity is left hanging at 0.4. How can I prevent this behaviour? I confirmed the event order by logging in to the console.

Comment: Please provide an example of this issue in code for us to debug. If you want to prevent a function from firing, have it check a global variable that is changed to signal allowing the function to fire.

Comment: I did not post the code because there's a lot going on there and the problem is limited to my description in the question.

Comment: Agree with Tom, I’ve run into similar issues and you can use a Boolean that changes to true at dragend, and in dragstart if it checks and sees the Boolean is true it forces the opacity change. If it’s still false, it runs the function as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Debouncing to delay the mouseover event reverting things.

```js
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let debounceTimer
    return function() {
        const context = this
        const args = arguments
            clearTimeout(debounceTimer)
                debounceTimer
            = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay)
    }
} 


window.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
  document.querySelector("body").innerText = "Mouse moving!";
});

window.addEventListener("mousemove", debounce(() => {
  document.querySelector("body").innerText = "not moving";
}, 300));
```

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
not moving
```